# Find all triples of positive integers $(x,y,z)$ such that $2^x+y^2=z!+14$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, contest-math

I have been working on the following practice problem:

**Find all triples of positive integers $(x,y,z)$ such that $2^x+y^2=z!+14$ and show that you have found all solutions.**

I have found the following $(1,6,4)$, $(2,4,3)$ and $(4,2,3)$ but I am unsure whether I have found all the solutions.

Comment: How did you find the solutions?

Comment: I rearranged the equation to this: $y^2=z!-2^x+14$ then basically tried different values for $x$ and $z$ such that RHS is a square number. It seemed like $y$ could only be even so that helped.

Comment: Some thoughts: Assume $z\geq 7 \Rightarrow z! \mod 14 = 0$. Now if we take the whole expression in $\mod 14$, we see that $2^x \mod 14$ can only have values $1, 2,4$ and 8; meaning that if we want $0 = 0$ on both sides, we would need $y^2 \mod 14 $ to be one of $6,10,12$ or $13$. But this never happens. So no solutions beyond $z \geq 7$.

Comment: $x,y,z$ must be positive integers. Sorry I must have accidentally deleted those conditions

Answer (score 3):

It is plain $y$ must always be even and therefore $y^2 \equiv 0 \mod 4$. Now, if $z \geq 4$, the right hand side is $2 \mod 4$.  Thus the only solution is $x = 1$, which is one of the solutions you have found.  It is also easy to see there are no solutions when $ z \leqslant 2$ (just test the very few cases).  which leaves $z = 3$ for the remaining solutions.

Comment: Thank you! Can I ask how you know $y$ is even? I just keep thinking that $n!$ can be 1.

Comment: You can test the few cases that occur when $z=1$.  $y$ has to be $1$ or $9$ and neither of those can work with any $x$.

Answer (score 1):

Since $x$ is positive, $2^x\equiv 0$ mod $2$.

(1) If $z=1$, the equation is $2^x+y^2 = 15$, hence $x = 1, 2, 3$ but then $y^2 = 13, 11, 7$, which is a contradiction.

(2) Let $z\ge 2$. Then $z!\equiv 0$ mod $2$, hence $y^2\equiv 0$ mod $2$, and $y$ is even, $y^2\equiv 0$ mod $4$.

(2-i) If $z = 2$, the equation is $2^x+y^2 = 16$, and $x = 1, 2, 3$, then $y^2 = 14, 12, 8$. Thus there's no solution in this case, too.

(2-ii) If $z=3$, the equation is $2^x+y^2 = 20$, so $x =1, 2, 3, 4$, $y^2 = 18, 16, 12, 4$. Hence only solutions in this case are $(2, 4, 3)$ and $(4, 2, 3)$.

(2-iii) Let $z\ge 4$. Then $z!\equiv 0$ mod $8$. Hence $2^x = z!-y^2+14\equiv 2$ mod $4$, and this forces $x = 1$. Then the equation is reduced to $y^2 = z!+12$. Let $y = 2y'$. Then $y'^2 = z!/4 + 3$.

(2-iii-a) If $z = 4$, $y'^2 = 6+3 = 9$, hence $y' = 3$ and $(1, 6, 4)$ is a solution.

(2-iii-b) If $z = 5$, $y'^2 = 33$, which is impossible.

(2-iii-c) If $z\ge 6$, $z!/4\equiv 0$ mod $4$. Hence $y'^2\equiv 0$ mod $4$, which is impossible.

Thus the three solutions $(1, 6, 4), (2, 4, 3)$ and $(4, 2, 3)$ are all solutions.